# Loading dialog before opening activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I have a list activity which loads data from JSON. Sometimes when connection is slow it shows black blank screen before it shows the activity. Instead of showing blank screen when I click on button to switch between activity, I want to show loading dialog box. Can anyone post code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

use Async task and in preExecute() open dialog and after loading data from server dismiss same in postExecute().

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
 ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this,"Loading", "Please wait for few minutes...", true);
 pd.setCancelable(true);
```

after data loading. call

```
pd.cancel();
```